# Discord.py Issue

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
import os
import discord.ext
#^ basic imports for other features of discord.py and python ^
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.id == 526450002986401805: message.channel.send('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/832402714603552838/978450412204085258/837F372D-4793-42F4-A24E-AFE399BB4B88.jpg')


client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Whenever I run the following code for a discord bot after I type a message so that the bot sends the link to the image I get the error:

```
main.py:8: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited
  if message.author.id == 526450002986401805: message.channel.send('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/832402714603552838/978450412204085258/837F372D-4793-42F4-A24E-AFE399BB4B88.jpg')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I am pretty new to coding, so sorry if it's something super simple!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited python.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402357/runtimewarning-coroutine-messageable-send-was-never-awaited-python-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'Messageable.send' was never awaited` tells you what went wrong here.

The library is `async` so if you want to send a message, to state an example here, you have to `await` it.

**Your new code:**

```py
if message.author.id == 526450002986401805:
    await message.channel.send('TheContentHere')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes much more sense now.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a more advanced version of whatever you're making

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Time Limit", color=0xff007f)
    embed.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/832402714603552838/978450412204085258/837F372D-4793-42F4-A24E-AFE399BB4B88.jpg")
    if message.author.id == 526450002986401805:

        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

the reason it gave you an "awaited" error is because the message was never awaited so it couldn't send.